# OpenGL Textures not applied correctly

Tags: opengl

I have some questions regarding adding color and textures to objects in OpenGL. I have a small scene. In this Scene I have two boxes.

Questions:

1. Let's say I want to have one box in a solid color and the other one with a texture. 
   Before I draw box nr. 1 i do `glcolor` and set the color of my cube. This work good as long as I don't bind a texture for the next cube. When I bind a texture both my cubes end up with the same texture. How do I get this to play nicely? Can I use both glColor and binding textures in the same "scene"?
2. It seems like the texture do not stretch to fit the entire side of the box. Is this because of me messing up texture coordinates or is it a setting for this somewhere?
3. Let's say I want to repeat the texture multiple times over a plane for example. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

**1** You need to first bind that texture, draw the cube, and unbind the texture with `glBindTexture(..., 0)`, then draw the other cubes

Note also to set the color of the textured cubes to white, so you see all colors of the cube.

**2** You propably don't set the texture coordinates right, note also that you need to send the polygons correctly

*Example*

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
<texture coordinates for point 1 of polygon 1>
<coordinates for point 1 of polygon 1>

<texture coordinates for point 2 of polygon 1>
<coordinates for point 2 of polygon 1>

<texture coordinates for point 3 of polygon 1>
<coordinates for point 3 of polygon 1>

<texture coordinates for point 1 of polygon 2>
<coordinates for point 1 of polygon 2>
...
```

**3** Just set as texturecoordinates a value greater than 1.0 and set the mode of texturing to repreating

Comment: 1. Someone said that I should do glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) or glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0). What is best and the right thing to do?

Comment: i would use glBindTexture because to activate you need just one call (glBindTexture(..., Id)) instead of two (glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); glBindTexture(..., Id))

Comment: @Quonux: Disabling texturing is the better method though. Texture unit 0 may have actual texture data attached (this is a legacy from OpenGL-1.0 which didn't have texture units, but used display lists to emulate texture objects). Binding texture 0 does not disable texturing fixed function OpenGL!

Comment: @datenwolf novadays on modern graphic cards there is no more "fixed function OpenGL" stuff, its all emulated with the driver

Comment: @Quonux: I know that (hint, look at the top users of the StackOverflow OpenGL tag). However when you're using the fixed function pipeline the driver must emulate the FFP. And that means with texturing enabled and texture unit 0 bound it may actually apply a texture, because in FFP texture unit 0 does not mean disabled. In fact binding 0 whereever you can bind something (VBO, PBO, FBO) does not mean "disable" but "default" (in the case of VBOs and PBOs default means client side memory access, and in OpenGL-4 with VAOs default means undefined, but not disabled!)

Comment: 2. I changed the Texture file now to a file that have the same height and width and the problem disappeared. The box is rendered correctly. So is this a requirement for texture files?